# GET variables not received from PHP redirect, is it a rewrite issue?

Tags: php, regex, mod-rewrite, get

I'm working on a basic blog and trying to create a method to edit already-created entries.  I know the code to render the entry in the edit view (admin page) works by manually passing the necessary GET variables in the url, e.g. `"localhost/simple_blog/admin.php?page=blog&url=first-entry"`.  This pulls all fields from the database without issue.

I have an .htaccess file performing rewrites, though:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /simple_blog/

RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png|css|js|inc\.php)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/(\w+)(|/)$ admin.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^admin/(\w+)/([\w-]+) admin.php?page=$1&url=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/([\w-]+) index.php?page=$1&url=$2
```

The link to edit an entry is in the format `"/simple_blog/admin/blog/first-entry"`, and hovering over the hyperlink on the page shows the reference to `"localhost/simple_blog/admin/blog/first-entry"` which is correct.  Clicking the link and viewing the source on the page that loads shows that no values are being received from the previous page, though.

I'm just hoping someone with a bit more mod_rewrite and RegEx experience can look at this with me and maybe point something out that I'm missing, either that or confirm that the issue is not with my rewrite rules and is definitely elsewhere.  I've triple-checked my functions, I receive no errors in Apache, and the access log merely shows that "first-entry" is being accessed by GET.

If this question is a dupe, PLEASE feel free to let me know and point me in the right direction.  If you feel like you need more info/code examples, let me know that, too. :)

(Yes, I'm using "PHP for Absolute Beginners" by Jason Lengstorf; I'm in chapter 7 right now.)

---

**EDIT: 1 Aug 2013**

I've tested my rules on http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and it appears that almost any url I test it on only matches the final rule, thereby only sending "index.php" back my way. I've checked my syntax both using the "PHP for Absolute Beginners" book and external resources.  Everything seems to check out.  Anyone have any idea why it's doing this?

Here's a screenshot of the Rewrite test results.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Given your log's applying `^/webdav$` and various other rules not present in your sample .htaccess above, there's probably OTHER rules being applied to your script somewhere else.

Comment: I noticed that too, Marc.  I was wondering if those might be Apple-generated RewriteRules via Mac OS X Server 10.8.  The volume that contains my site files was being shared via WebDAV, so that might have something to do with it.  I turned off WebDAV, but no change.  Anything else you see that might help?

Comment: check the main httpd.conf files, or in the directories above your site's document root. there could be a .htaccess lurking in any of the parent directories doing it.

Comment: I found an additional Rewrite in the main httpd.conf.  Didn't find any other .htaccess files in parent/child directories, and no other Rewrite rules in the .conf files I searched besides the one in httpd.conf.  I commented it out, restarted apache, and the issue persisted. :/

Answer (score 0):

Even though you've declared a `RewriteBase`, you can't exclude it from the pattern matching side of the Rules. A lot of the online testers don't support things like `RewriteBase`. Try this and see if it works.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /simple_blog/

RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png|css|js|inc\.php)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^simple_blog/admin/([\w-]+)/?$ admin.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^simple_blog/admin/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+) admin.php?page=$1&url=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^simple_blog/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+) index.php?page=$1&url=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^simple_blog/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the image embed, Zero.  Not enough rep. :)  It looks like you're right about online tools not supporting RewriteBase.  If I remove "simple_blog" from my URL, the tester matches the rules without issue.  However, having the base in my actual htaccess file does not seem to work for the admin links.  The index links work without issue.

Comment: @thankyour is the admin directory at `duchess.local/admin` or `duchess.local/simple_blog/admin`? All of the files we're redirecting to are supposed to be in the `simple_blog` directory also?

Comment: "Admin" is actually a reference to `admin.php` within `/simple_blog/`. All files we're redirecting to are within the simple_blog directory, hence why the recommended structure is to have the RewriteBase at `/simple_blog/`.  The goal is to have `$page` and `$url` from example `duchess.local/simple_blog/admin/$page/$url` passed to admin.php as GET variables.  No dice so far.  The index.php rewrites work just fine, though.